# Teamcity startup hangs at the jetbrains.buildServer.STARTUP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tomcat, teamcity

When running Teamcity 2017.1 on Ubuntu last visible startup log confirms startup, port 8111 is opened, but requests are not served.

Answer (score 0):

The startup might be just spending X minutes to get enough entropy to for session ID.

On Digital Ocean it actually took 5 minutes.

Using /dev/urandom is a bit faster but less secure (systemd example):

```
Environment='TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'
```

see also https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp#Entropy_Source